# Qt: Session management error in opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to run following script

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Capture Video from Camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when i tried to run it in the Ubuntu terminal it gives me this `Qt: Session management error` and 2 unwanted frames along with my output.

[image]

> can you guys help me how can i get rid of this error and those unwanted
> frames?

Comment: This apparently is QT incompatibility issue between your host OS and OpenCV QT version. Try to build OpenCV from source on your machine and install. Looks like you deleted your previous question on the similar topic?

Comment: Yeah, I recently change Ubuntu graphics option from Intel to NVIDIA so i thought it was because of that so i reset it but still getting same error and after running same script 2 to 3 times it shows output otherwise it shows nothing.

Comment: @MilindDeore as you said  it is because of QT incompatibility how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of opencv are you using? I see an issue with recent release [here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/290). May be try 3.x version.

Comment: ```sudo apt -y install libgtk2.0-dev libtbb-dev qt5-default``` and rebuild opencv

Comment: @MilindDeore I installed opencv using `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python` command.

Comment: Guys this `sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv` command worked for me. i found this here https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thank you man, i did not try whatever you suggest but i think it is same as i found. thank you

Comment: But still i want to know why this happened  in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Cos of you installed opencv before OS environment packages. First OS environment then opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys after finding many blogs and resources finally i got this and it is worked for me.

Instead of using pip for opencv installation use below command

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv
```

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/

**NOTE - I think this issue is with Ubuntu 20.04**

Answer (score 0):

I removed opencv as `pip uninstall opencv-python` and reinstalled it again with `pip install opencv-python`

It worked for me